# How to find a control in a repeater with IndexOf C#

Tags: c#, repeater, indexof, findcontrol, items

I want to know if it's possible to find a control in a repeater but by approximation. I mean, I have some controls with end "....EditMode" and I want to catch them all and modify some attribute

Something like this

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
{
     HtmlGenericControl divEditMode = item.FindControl("....IndexOf ("EditMode")");
     if(divEditMode != null)
     {
          divEditMode.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
{
  foreach (var control in item.Controls)
  {
     if(control.ID.EndsWith("EditMode"))
     {
          control.Visible = false;
     }
  }
}
```

If I understand your wishes.

Answer (score 1):

The way to accomplish this is to loop through the controls "by hand" instead of using FindControl. You can use the [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection of the RepeaterItem to list all controls and analyze their ids. 
As controls are organized as a tree, you should recursively inspect also the Controls collections of the controls on the top level.

```
private IEnumerable<Control> GetEditControls(ControlCollection controls)
{
    var lst = new List<Control>();
    if (controls == null)
        return lst;
    foreach(var ctrl in controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.Id.EndsWith("EditMode"))
           lst.Add(ctrl);
        lst.AddRange(GetControls(ctrl.Controls);
    }
    return lst;
}
// ...
foreach(RepeaterItem item in repeater1.Items)
{
     var divsEditMode = GetEditControls(item.Controls);
     foreach(var divEditMode in divsEditMode)
     {
          divEditMode.Visible = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Something small, but in the second block of code, you'll want to set the data type of the `divsEditMode` variable to `IEnumerable<Control>`

Comment: Thanks for the hint; fixed it.